# No puedo leer el código de los componentes en Angular, el archivo no se muestra en el editor porque es Binario

Tags: angular, typescript, component

Hola buenas tardes compañeros, he clonado un proyecto de Github, ya lo he actualizado y todo para la versión que yo tengo instalada en el pc de Angular pero al momento de ver el código de algún componente me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay otros pocos componentes que si deja ver si código como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo lo que está pasando, agradezco mucho si alguno tuviera la respuesta. Gracias de ante mano

Comment: ¿Has probado de abrirlo en otros editores?  ¿O hacer un `type dashboard.components.ts` desde un powershell (o como se llame en windows al terminal) para ver lo que contiene realmente?  A ver si va a ser un virus.

Comment: Hola, si brother, lo intente en Atom y allí si se muestra el código pero no entiendo entonces porque en VSC no me muestra el código. No creo que tenga un virus porque este repo lo saque de la plataforma de platzi

Comment: Por la captura de VS code, puede ser que no te funcione en Atom? Has actualizado los paquetes con npm update, si es así te aconsejo, que no te descargues el proyecto de nuevo, y que revises el package.json, para saber que versión de angular está usando e instalarte la misma y revisar si en los tutoriales de platzi se muestra la versión de nodejs, ya que no todas las versiones de node son compatibles con las de angular, por ejemplo node v14.... no es compatible con la última versión de Angular para  ello debes instalarte la v16.... ,y pase al revés

Comment: Cal revés lo nuevo no funciona con versiones anteriores o tienes que hacer algún apaño, tienes nvm que es un gestor de versiones de node, puedes tener varias de node y en principio una deAngular, pero en este al instalarte primero node y angular, te permitirá tener dos versiones como máximo, si no tendrías que trabajar con Docker pero esto es algo más complicado.

Comment: Juan Carlos Lo solucione actualizando npm, me toco desinstalarlo, volverlo a instalar y luego actualizarlo, muchas gracias!